# Plot two arraylist in android using androidplot

Tags: android, arraylist, graph, androidplot

I have this two arraylist

```
static List<Date> xplot= new ArrayList<Date>();//[04:40:18, 04:40:35, 04:40:52, 04:41:09, 04:47:17, 04:47:47, 04:48:04]
static List<String> yplot= new ArrayList<String>();//[729.00,852.00,725.00,789.00,638.00,478.00,798.00]
```

having some data in it and now i want to plot a graph using androidplot
(https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) tutorial but not able to understand. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Androidplot operates on instances of `Number` so the first thing you need to do is convert your `List<Date>` and `List<String>` lists to `List<Number>`.

You can convert a `Date` to a long timestamp by using `Date.getTime()`.  Your `String` values appear to be float values so you can pass those values directly into a `Float` constructor.

Once you have your lists of converted values, you can turn them into an `XYSeries` like this:

```
XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(xVals, yVals, "my series");
```

Comment: can you be more specific on how to convert List<Date> to Number i mean  how will hh:mm:ss be converted to numbers

Comment: I cant really be much more specific than mentioning `Date.getTime()`.  If you're new to Java you may want to read up on [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).  Basically this language feature allows you to do this: `Number n = dateInstance.getTime();`.  Date instances do not store formatting, ie `hh:mm:ss` etc. so you don't need to worry about that.